# dotnet pack not working when project file passed

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have the following issue:

I am running `dotnet pack --no-build -c Release .\Client.csproj` and am getting `error NU5026: The file 'Client\bin\Release\net7.0\Client.dll' to be packed was not found on disk`

However, when I don't pass a csproj, it works:

`Successfully created package 'Client\bin\x64\Release\Client.1.0.0.nupkg'`

It seems the 2 flavors of packing don't search for the DLL with the same path (one has x64 in it)

The csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <StaticWebAssetsEnabled>false</StaticWebAssetsEnabled>

    <!-- tried this trick, didn't work-->
    <!--Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform-->

  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and an excerpt of the sln file:

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {ED0EAE71-53F9-4C7B-BD5A-02B960CAFD5E}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {ED0EAE71-53F9-4C7B-BD5A-02B960CAFD5E}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {ED0EAE71-53F9-4C7B-BD5A-02B960CAFD5E}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {ED0EAE71-53F9-4C7B-BD5A-02B960CAFD5E}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {A4B1F3EA-12B9-4F54-B1C2-CE0401DC0335}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {A4B1F3EA-12B9-4F54-B1C2-CE0401DC0335}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {A4B1F3EA-12B9-4F54-B1C2-CE0401DC0335}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {1251856A-31D8-4464-A039-62134CBC30FF}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Adding an OutputPath for the release configuration seems to align the paths used by the build and packing, but I still wonder why without that change, the path used by `dotnet pack some.csproj` doesn't match the outpath of the build (like `dotnet pack` without a csproj), since they supposedly read the exact same files

I also found the following solutions to work, but can't rely on them:

- building during packing (removing `--no-build`), because we do build in 2 steps so that we don't pack systematically (in local for example), and so we can version packed artifacts in AzureDevOps
- packing during building (with `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>`), same reason
- not specifying a csproj in the packing command: as we don't want to pack every project, but just a subset of them